# Db2 Count(*) AS + query

Tags: java, db2

I'm having a hard time with query. The thing I'm trying to do is this.

```
public ObservableList<Query_3_11> getQuery_3_11() {
    ObservableList<Query_3_11> query_3_11List = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT town, COUNT(*) AS numofclients FROM Clients GROUP BY town ORDER BY numofclients DESC");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Query_3_11 query_3_11 = new Query_3_11();
            query_3_11.setMiasto(rs.getString("town"));
            query_3_11.setliczbaKlientow(rs.getInt("numofclients"));
            query_3_11List.add(query_3_11);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return query_3_11List;
```

Basically my program prints out name of the cities, but there are blank spaces into Number of Clients column. Here is a picture.

[screenshot of gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtFPT.png)

Here's the query class.

```
public class Query_3_11 {

private String town;
private int numofclients;

public String getTown() {
    return town;
}

public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}

public int getnumofclients() {
    return numofclients;
}

public void setnumofclients(int numofclients) {
    this.numofclients = numofclients;
}
}
```

If I forgot something important please do tell me. Tbh it's my first java program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe what are you trying to achieve, and what is exactly your question.

Comment: I want exactly the same output in my java program like this.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18820233/db2output.png

Comment: What's your DB2 version and platform, and what is the driver version (`java -cp /the/path/to/db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`)?